# How to access my post from a adjacent page in tumblr

Tags: tumblr

OK, so I've created an adjacent page in tumblr for my blog (in customize -> Pages -> add page), but It seems that I can't use any varibles to get my posts such as in

```
{block:Post}
   {block:Audio}
      <div class="audio">
         {AudioPlayerBlack}
      </div> 
   {/block:Audio}
{/block:Post}
```

How can I access this variables or even my very posts from an adjacent page (like your_page.tumblr/adjacent_page)?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot.

Pages get rendered as a text post but with no date attached to it, so whatever you have in your `{block:Text}` block will be rendered.